# Allowing X number of instaces of a Electron application

Tags: electron

I would like to allow a user to open up to X concurrent instances of an Electron application. How can my application count the number of its open instances?

Comment: Take a look at a window manager (or you could write your own one I guess). [electron-window-manager](https://github.com/TamkeenLMS/electron-window-manager)

Comment: Thks @Hevlastka but  electron-window-manager manages BrowserWindow instances like windows at my application. I'm  looking for application instances counting solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a supported way to do that.

You could do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/ocboogie/6dac0a93707c4a524a73b0597cea3c74). But this is probably a last resort.